# How do you check to see if a variable has changed every second or less in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, function

I am using an if statement to check the value of a BOOLEAN when i click on a button. When the button is clicked if the value is false i want to display a UIActivityIndicator and if the value is true i want to push the new view. I can do this fine but i want the view to change automatically when the BOOLEAN Becomes true if the user has already clicked the button.

So my question is how do you check to see if a value has changed everysecond or less?

Comment: Checking periodically to see if something changed is an example of polling.  Not an efficient solution compared to KVO.  Avoid polling when possible.

Answer (score 12):

Look into KVO — Key-Value Observing — to trigger an action when a variable changes its value.

In your view controller's `-viewWillAppear:` method, for example, add the observer:

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myBoolean" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

In your `-viewWillDisappear:` method, unregister the observer:

```
[self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myBoolean"];
```

It's important to do this last step, so that the `-dealloc` method doesn't throw an exception.

Finally, set up the observer method to do something when there is a change to `myBoolean`:

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqual:@"myBoolean"]) { 
        // The BOOL value of myBoolean changed, so do something here, like check
        // what the new BOOL value is, and then turn the indicator view on or off
    }
}
```

The Key-Value Observing pattern is a good, general way to trigger something when an object's value changes somewhere. Apple has written a good ["quick-start" document](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/KeyValueObserving_QuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html) that introduces this topic.

Comment: how does this apply if the variable i want to check is in another view controller

Comment: Instead of sending the message addObserver to self, you send it to the other view controller.

Comment: The use of self is not a requirement, although you want to make sure that you un-register any observers added to other objects before they are deallocated. Otherwise your app will likely crash, trying to send an "observation" to a released observer object, which no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look a [Key-Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) (often referred to simply as KVO). It uses the language's dynamic introspective capabilities to implement exactly this functionality for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look into the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).